# How to change the color of the launcher background Android Kotlin?

Tags: android

I looked for a way but I didn't find it, where I was still a beginner for Android and when I created my project it was finished and there was a problem where I would change the color of the launcher background without having to use the splashscreen, Please help me to provide a tutorial so that the launcher background color can change according to what I want, not the default color, which is white

| before | after |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before] | [image: After] |

Tell me how to change the color of the launcher background like in the after image???

The problem I am facing can be resolved, I hope someone will be able to help me

Comment: It's in the documentation here. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#set-theme It's called a splash screen, not a launcher.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

> The customizable elements of a splash screen consist of the app icon, icon background, and window background:

> 4 The window background consists of a single opaque color. If the window background is set and is a plain color, it is used by default if the attribute isn't set.

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

or

```
context.window.decorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
```